# Can supervised learning be used to solve the inverted pendulum problem?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, robotics, supervised-learning

I know that [reinforcement learning has been used to solve the inverted pendulum problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Q14EjnOJZc).

Can supervised learning be used to solve the [inverted pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum) problem?

For example, there could be an interface (e.g. a joystick) with the cart-pole system, which the human can use to balance the pole and, at the same time, collect a dataset for supervised learning. Has this been done before?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, for example [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.11592.pdf) paper uses YouTube videos to learn how to play difficult game Montezuma's Revenge

Comment: You may also be interested in [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/14167/2444).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can, and yes this has been researched and done before. By using supervised learning, you give the *machine* some data, and it will try to figure the best way to analyze and predict the next movement in case of an **inverted pendulum** problem.

I found a complete paper for this problem: [Neural network control of an inverted pendulum on a cart](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228798837_Neural_network_control_of_an_inverted_pendulum_on_a_cart) by Valeri Mladenov et al.